# How to jump to call log activity in Android 5.0 from third-party Apps?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-5.0-lollipop

How to jump to call log activity in Android 5.0 from third-party Apps? Before, I used:

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON);
```